# Using a 10V stepper motor with a 12V controller board

Tags: voltage, stepper-motor

What should I do when using a 10V .5A NEMA14 stepper motor with this board: https://reprap.org/wiki/MiniRambo (beyond setting proper current limits in firmware)? If I understand it correctly, the board uses 12V by default as it normally controlls 12V NEMA17 motors. Will the voltage difference be a problem and if so, how can I fix it? If I just use resistors, won't it limit the current too?
The board uses A4982 stepper motor drivers, the datasheet is here: http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/files/datasheets/a4982-datasheet.ashx

Comment: Arguably, your motor's coil voltage rating is  *too high* for your controller.  You typically want a controller supplied with *several times* the motor's nominal voltage, otherwise you will have poor performance at speed.  But perhaps your application only moves slowly or does not need the motor's rated torque, for example a 3d printer Z axis will often have cheap motors with high coil impedance, while the X, Y and extruder might have ~4v motors, all supplied from 12v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rated voltage doesn't really matter much for steppers, as long as the current is regulated you should be good to go

Comment: In that case, I should be able to even use a 3V motor and as long as the current is in check it should work, right?

Comment: This is oversimple: the voltage matters a great deal, in that **the supply voltage should be several times the motor voltage** unless it is a fairly low performance requirement or the motor is oversized for the need.

Comment: Looks like Chris is right. Steppers are used and rated differently from other motors.

Answer (score 0):

A 10V 0.5 stepper will draw 5W in each winding or 10W max with an 80'C temp rise at full step which means the DCR of each coil is 10V/0.5A = 20 Ohms

The design uses Current sense Rs 0.1 Ohm with Imax programmable by DAC software 100%=2V/8Rs which exceeds the 500mA.

The drivers are 350mohm max so 12V / (0.35+20+0.1)ohms= 587 mA, so 12V may be too hot in certain step positions if using microstepping.  This temp. rise can be improved with a 35mm microfan attached to motor.